# Action not being called when UIBarButtonItem tapped

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

Note:  I've only tested this on the simulator.

I want to add the target-action in code instead of connecting it as an IBAction in Interface Builder.

`theButton` is on the navigation bar at the top left, created in IB.

Steps:

1. Declared `theButton` as an IBOutlet and connected it in IB.
2. Added this in `viewDidLoad`:

   ```
   self.theButton.target = self;
   self.theButton.action = @selector(theAction);
   ```
3. I'm testing `theAction` by this:

   ```
   - (void)theAction {
   NSLog(@"theAction called");
   //do some other stuff
   }
   ```

When I click on `theButton` in the simulator, nothing happens.  I don't see the NSLog statement at all.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Had to do with my configuration.  I'm using a tab bar controller that uses the same view controller for multiple tabs.  Each view controller shows different filtered data for some tab items.

Therefore, in such a configuration, you must be sure to connect the IBOutlets for each view controller that's contained by a tab bar item.  I only connected one, which is why it wasn't working for some of the tab items.

Answer (score 4):

Have you connected the action to the button in interface-builder?

If not you should declare the action in your .h file

```
-(IBAction)theAction;
```

Change the name of the action on your .m file

```
-(IBAction)theAction{

}
```

And finealy connect the action to the button in interface-builder.

Comment: no need for that since it's done programmatically with self.theButton.target = self; and self.theButton.action = @selector(theAction);

Comment: Edited my answer for programmatically use.

Comment: Please note that, *UIBarButtonItem* won't respond to *addTarget:action:forControlEvents:* method

Comment: Just for any future readers.  The compiler gives me an error in Xcode 4.  It does not like the asterisk.

Comment: i have the same problem on 7.1.
in IB UIBarButtonItem is linked to IBAction by Ctrl+Drag
But it is not called.
On 8.1 it works.

Answer (score 3):

Change your function as below:

```
-(IBAction)theAction{
    NSLog(@"theAction called");
    //do some other stuff
}
```

And if you called like "@selector(theAction:);"
then change function as below:

```
-(IBAction)theAction:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"theAction called");
    //do some other stuff
}
```

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Let me know in case of any difficulty.